# php, mysql, is it posible after inserting a row and uploading doc automatical send email to releted client

Tags: php, mysql

for example here is a client list table:

```
tbl_client:

    cl_name:    //primary auto
    cl_email:   //unique
```

now there is a table where i will insert data:

```
tbl_data

    d_id:
    d_title
    d_file    // this will be file and uploaded
    cl_name
```

as you see in table of (tbl_data) there is a column name(**cl_name**) which is referenced to **tbl_client**

now if i insert new record to table **tbl_data** and uploads file for example

```
d_id   d_title   d_file   u_name
1      text      f1.pdf    client1
```

the idea is the system should send an email to **client1** attaching file automatically.

is it possible with php or any other solution.

regards and thanks for your patient reading my question.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible with PHP.... perhaps if you hired a developer they'd write it for you

Comment: @MarkBaker,just trying to learn,i tough there would be people passed the way before me so i could use their experience and fine the nearest way if you could point me some link where i could start learning it.

Comment: Asking for help when code you've written doesn't work as you expect is an acceptable question on SO; but asking a question that is basically asking people to write code for you isn't

Comment: @MarkBaker i never ask to write code, as u said yes this posible means u have learn from some where and u have much knowlege in net so it means you know where in internet are good examples related subject and you can point out me and it will take only your one menute at time if i my self search with out asking any one may be it will take my tow day to fine a good example in net regarding the subject. and thanks for dwonMark jajaja

Comment: @abas-rafiq You've been on SO long enough to know that `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` So if you weren't asking us to write it for you, then what were you asking that isn't covered by the above?

Comment: And for reference, I didn't downvote you

Comment: it's ok, thanks, now as it's posible i will go and search the solution or library for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the query succeeded on the databse and then send a mail with php.

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $querygoeshere))
{
    //Mail function here.
    mail():
}else
{
    //Error handling goes here.
}
```

Ofcourse you can check out the documentation on the various mysqli_* stuff and mail functions on [php.net](http://php.net)